# Find the lowest sum path from 2d Array

Tags: java, algorithm

Just thinking about the one algorithm below is the statement for that

Given a matrix, with each node having a value. You start from `0,0` and have to reach `n,m`. From `i,j` you can either go to `i+1,j` or `i,j+1`. When you step on each block, the value on that block gets added to your current score. What’s the minimum initial score you must carry so that you can always reach `n,m`(through any possible path) having positive score at the end.

Eg:

```
Matrix ->        2   3   4
                -5  -6   7
                 8   3   1
```

Ans -> 6 – for path 2,-5,-6,3,1 we need initial score of 6 so that when we land on 1, we have a positive score of 1

So I can do this using brute force and Dynamic programming, but still thinking for approach which could be better then this, please share ur thoughts, just thoughts/idea I do not need implementation, as I can do this.

Comment: If you're asking about ideas for an algorithm I don't think SO is the place. Maybe try [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This sounds like a classic A* algorithm. Maybe the dijkstra algorithm helps.

Comment: You cannot hope for an algorithm that is more time efficient than `O(|E|) = O(m * n)`  and space complexity `O(min(m, n))` is also pretty good... Go for the dynamic programming solution (bottom up)! @Burkhard I hope you are not serious... Those algorithms are a total overkill for this problem and Dijkstra won't work (negative edge weights).

Comment: @fabian is right, since your it would take `O(nm)` to read the map, so even if your algorithm could run better than this complexity doesn't help. If there are no other constraints, simple DP will do.

Answer (score -1):

There's many search algorithm, i encourage you reading these Wikipedia pages :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

One possible solution, is to transform the array to graph and apply shortest paths algorithms to it, another solution is to use some IA algorithms such as A*.

Link to Wikipedia for A* (prounced A Star) :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: @fabian thank you for remembring me that, i will edit my answer.